# How to merge two RGB raster tables with overlap by max in each band in postgis?

Tags: postgis, raster, postgresql, union

I need to merge RGB raster tables from Sentinel-2 data into a mosaic of same date using ST_Union(), but following the example of [Postgis manual](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.3/RT_ST_Union.html) for all bands and all input rasters like [this one](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/2474) I got errors.

Ps.: All rasters were processed to ressample and reproject to same resolution and projection before to upload at postgresql server.

```
--My code

select ST_Union(ARRAY[rast1, rast2], 'MAX') from 
    sentinel.rasterTable1 as rast1,
          sentinel.rasterTable2 as rast2; 

-- the error
ERROR:  function st_union(sentinel.rasterTable1, sentinel.rasterTable2) does not exist
```

How can I fix this to get the max by each band?

```
  #################################################################
```

First appoach by @Pierre using this code:

```
 create table mergedData as SELECT ST_Union(rast, 'MAX') rast FROM 
 (SELECT rast FROM rasterTable1  
  UNION ALL
  SELECT rast FROM rasterTable2) foo
```

[image: Example of code application]

Aparently, only copy the first image listted in the code above.

Comment: How do you define max for an RGB image? Max of each band?

Comment: @user30184 Yes, by each band.

Comment: Is rasterTable1 a table or a field. If the former, you want, to specify the raster in ARRAY, eg, ARRAY[table1.rast, table2.rast], ....

Comment: @JohnPowellakaBarça rasterTable1 is a table.

Comment: Well that is your problem. Union takes the raster field not the table name

Comment: So, how I need to change to run the St_Union correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no raster function taking an array of rasters yet. You need to union the two tables before:

```
SELECT ST_Union(rast, 'MAX') rast
FROM (SELECT rast FROM rasterTable1 
      UNION ALL
      SELECT rast FROM rasterTable2) foo
```

Comment: aparently the code don't merge the tables, only copy the first table listed in the code. look at the figure at the question which I got from your suggestion.

Comment: @Pierre, really, that isn't very clear from the docs which manifestly show an example taking a setof rasters.

Comment: @Isaque It's probably because the black areas are nodata values. The result of the MAX operation becomes nodata. What are the nodata values?

Comment: @JohnPowellakaBarça a setof raster is not the same as an array of raster...

Comment: @Pierre the nodata values were defined as "0.0"  when I pre-process the data (mask clouds, transform to reflectance and so on..).

Comment: Doh, indeed a set of rows and an array are not the same, still your solution with the UNION SELECT works perfectly well.

Comment: So what if you unset the nodata value like this: ST_SetBandNodataValue(rast, NULL)? You can reset it afterward.

Answer (score 0):

Following the solution proposed by @Pierre, it merge the raster tables in a perfect way.

```
  create table testmerge as SELECT ST_Union(ST_SetBandNodataValue(rast, NULL), 'MAX') rast
                      FROM (SELECT rast FROM rasterTable1  
                        UNION ALL
                         SELECT rast FROM rasterTable2) foo;

################################## The result
```

[image: Merged image result]